# Как в android выполнить действие после закрытия фрагмента в котором это действие было запущенно?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-fragment

Проблема вот в чем, есть фрагмент в котором пользователь может изменить данные о себе ,и при нажатии кнопки изменить в этом фрагменте, отсылается запрос на сервер,после выполнения логики, сервер в ответе отсылает ,внеслись изменения или нет, и если изменения были внесены то в приложении я записываю новые данные в shared preferences. А как мне быть если у пользователя в момент выполнения запроса (до того момента как был получен ответ сервера) выключиться телефон,или просто будет нажата кнопка назад и фрагмент закроется? Ведь данные я не успею сохранить ,а на сервере изменения внесуться,и пользователь об этом даже не узнает.
Использовать сервисы для этой ситуации немогу, так как нужно будет выполнить логику внутри фрагмента после выполнения запроса (но если фрагмент был закрыт и приложения вылетит это не важно, главное чтобы новые данные я успел сохранить)

Comment: 1. Используйте асинхронный запрос и реактивное программирование (JavaRX) для подписки на факт получения данных во фрагменте
2. Запрашивайте данные с сервера там, где они вам нужны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если во время выполнения запроса устройство выключилось, то тут ничего никогда не поделаешь.

В случае с переключением фрагментов, то нужно, чтобы некоторый менеджер, не привязанный к жизненному циклу фрагмента, выполнял запрос и получал ответ. Если необходимо в UI отобразить уведомление о том, что все успешно прошло, то нужно, чтобы активити подписалась на события от этого менеджера, а он в свою очередь должен уведомить подписанную активити о получении ответа. Подписка и отписка активити на события в менеджере должна быть в методах жизненного цикла (Например, подписываемся в `onStart()`, а отписываемся в `onStop()`).

Конечно, все запросы можно делать и в активити, но архитектурно это совершенно неверный подход.

Если всё же такая ситуация возникает (когда на сервере изменения внесены, а на клиенте ответ не был получен), то при очередном запуске приложения должна быть фоновая синхронизация данных между сервером и клиентом (проще говоря, нужно при переходе на конкретный экран пытаться подтянуть с сервера актуальные данные, но не так, чтобы экран повис на загрузке. Если сервер долго не отвечает, лучше показать старые закешированные данные).

Еще вариант есть такой, что когда в конкретном фрагменте выполняется запрос, который прям важно выполнить, то вешайте `ProgressDialog`, и если кто-то во время, пока выполняется запрос, жмет кнопку назад, то закрывать `ProgressDialog` и показывать другой диалог с вопросом "Отменить выполнение запроса?", ну и кнопки Да/Нет. Если нет, то снова показываем крутилку, если да, то останавливаем запрос.

Comment: Спасибо за такой ответ,очень сильно выручили целый день убил на то что-бы найти решение. А можно поподробней про мененджер,что это за мененджер,как его реализовать?

Comment: Это просто отдельный объект, никак не завязанный на жизненном цикле и существующий на протяжении работы всего приложения. Можно назвать его синглетоном, но реализовывать его именно как паттерн `Singleton` не советую. Если не знакомы с внедрением зависимостей или фабриками, то просто храните его в поле вашего класса-Application и получайте откуда хотите, но главное, чтобы этот менеджер вообще не хранил ссылки на `Context`, иначе утечки памяти поймаете.

Comment: Окей,еще раз большое спасибо